# UIScrollView - detect second touch while scrolling

Tags: iphone, events, uiscrollview, touch

I have a subclass of UIScrollView that implements this method:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     NSLog(@"touches: %d", [[event allTouches] count]);


    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

This gets called when I first touch the scroll view. However, if I begin dragging the scroll view, then place a second finger down, touchesBegan does not get called. I need to detect when a second touch has occured in the scrollview, even if it is currently scrolling. Any ideas?

EDIT: Two touches are registered if I start with two, but if I start with one, begin scrolling, then put a 2nd finger down it is not registered.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure [`multipleTouchEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/multipleTouchEnabled) is set to `YES` on your scroll view.

You can also set this in Interface Builder. Look for 'Multiple Touch' checkbox.

Comment: self.multipleTouchEnabled = YES; is in the initWithFrame method, and I have verified that it is being set.